# Run GQL query from Google Cloud Workflows

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, gql

I have a simple GQL query, `SELECT * FROM PacerFeed WHERE pollInterval >= 0` that I want to run in a GCP Workflow wit the Firestore connector.

What is the database ID in the parent field? Is there a way I can just provide the whole query rather than the yaml'd fields? If not, what is the correct yaml args for this query?

```
    - getFeeds:
        call: googleapis.firestore.v1.projects.databases.documents.runQuery

        // These args are not correct, just demonstrative.
        args:
          parent: projects/{projectId}/databases/{database_id}/documents
          body:
            structuredQuery:
              from: [PacerFeed]
              select: '*'
              where: pollInterval >= 0
        result: got
```

PS can someone with more pts add a 'google-cloud-workflows' tag?

Comment: `(default)` is the default database

Comment: Is your database in Datastore mode?  If so, then using the Firestore API for queries won't work as the query won't be able to find a matching index.  From https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/Overview "The Firestore connector only supports databases created in Native mode. Operations will fail if used on a database in Datastore mode. To learn more about the difference between the two, see Choosing between Native mode and Datastore mode."

Comment: @Tom, did the previous comments address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer in order for other community members with similar questions will find this helpful.

Comment: It somewhat answers my question and is more informative than GCP Support :D 
Im still chasing a solution before posing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As in the comments, Jim pointed out what over a week of back and forth with GCP support could not. The db must be in Firestore Native mode.

I suggest not using GCP Workflows at all. The documentation sucks, there is not schema, the only thing GCP Support can do is tell you to hire a MSP to fill the doc gaps and point you to [an example](https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/googleapis/firestore/v1/projects.databases.documents/runQuery) ... that does not include the parent field.